# Can spells like Sacred Flame and Chill Touch be used against a creature on the other side of Leomund's Tiny Hut?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can spells like Sacred Flame and Chill Touch be used against a creature on the other side of Leomund's Tiny Hut?

The wording of the spell states *"Spells and other magical effects can't extend through the dome or be cast through it."*

Spells like Sacred Flame, Chill Touch, Wall of Fire and Dimension Door do not need to be cast through anything. These spells don't need to travel, the effect is simply appears at the target.

I think that that RAW, the answer is yes. RAI it would be no since the spell is intended as a safe place to rest. What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr: No. For several reasons, below:**

---

### 1. The spell wording:

> (...)  or be cast through it.

If the caster is outside and the effect is inside, it has been cast through the barrier. The spell wording forbades it.

### 2. Cover:

Most spells cannot be cast if there is even a glass window between caster and target point.

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind total cover.

The hut barrier, even if you could see inside, grants total cover. And finally...

### 3. You cannot cast into what you cannot see:

> The dome is opaque from the outside,

Therefore, anyone outside cannot see inside the hut, and cannot cast targeting inside, since you need to see the target. Even if the particular spell does not require sight, you would still need to find out on which of the 12 spaces inside the hut the target is.

Comment: Actually, you only need to see the target if the spell says so

Comment: @DaleM there is only a 1 in 12 chance that you target the right square inside the hut's 10 ft hemisphere

Comment: Not seeing someone doesn't mean you have to guess their location. You only need to guess if they have spent an action to hide.

Comment: ... or if you can't see them for some reason.  They don't need to "spend an action to hide" if you can't see them in the first place.  That would be silly.

Comment: Makes sense. Still can't cast Sacred Flame through the hut (cast through wording), however it can be cast through a glass window. Jeremy Crawford stated that spells like Sacred Flame only require a target you can see. It also ignores cover. So it can be used around a corner with a mirror to get LoS.

Comment: @PhilBoncer Actually, they do need to spend an action to Hide, even when invisible. Just because you can't see somebody doesn't mean you can't *hear* them. Stealth covers both in 5E.

Comment: There is a podcast about targeting through hearing with Jeremy Crawford, I believe it is one of the January ones. It goes over this pretty well.